# _BitScanForward64 can not be found

Tags: c++, g++, bit-manipulation, intel, intrinsics

I am writing a chess engine and would like to use Intel's intrinsic [_BitScanForward64](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=1786,1785,5432,5437,5473,4048,1152,2010,3835,4512,4515,4048,4047,3504,3503,409,409,409&text=_BitScanForward64) but I can't find it.

Including [_mm_popcnt_u64](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=1786,1785,5432,5437,5473,4048,1152,2010,3835,4512,4515,4048,4047,3504,3503,408,409,409,409,408,4379&text=_mm_popcnt_u64) on the other hand worked just fine.

What I have checked so far:

- searching for declaration of `_mm_popcnt_u64` -> `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/popcntintrin.h`
- searching for declaration of `_BitScanForward64` -> no results
- I installed `g++-10` to check if this is due to an old version of gcc -> still no declaration

So it makes sense that `g++` can't find it. But how can I provide it? Or am I missing something else?

My machine:

- Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 8
- 64-bit
- gcc version 7.5.0

Comment: That intrinsic for bsf is only provided by MSVC and maybe ICC, not gcc/clang I think.  If you don't need backwards compat with old CPUs, you can use [`_tzcnt_u64`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX_512,Other&text=tzcnt), or if you don't mind GNU C extensions, `__builtin_ctzll`.  C++ portably exposes popcount via `std::bitset<64>` `.count()`, but I forget if it has a find first / last.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter pointed out: This specific intrinsic is not provided by gcc.